# Handy DataRow.Field<> version - with null checking

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I'm using c# to get data from DB. I know there is as Field<> extenstion to DataRow:

`public static T? Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)`

But, I'd like to have a method that is more handy to me, especially:

- returns default(T) whene row["COLUMNNAME"] is null or DBNull (I know i can pass int?, but it is not handy)
- don't throw exception when accessing Int16 comlumn as In32 (dr.Field<int>("COMLUMINT16"))
- nice, to have work when cast int to string (dr.Field<string>("COLUMNINT"))

So I've wrote an alternative version:

```
        public static T Get<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
        {
            if (row == null || row.IsNull(columnName))
                return default(T);
            else
            {
                if (row[columnName].GetType() == typeof(T))
                    return row.Field<T>(columnName);
                else
                    return (T)row[columnName];
                //return (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[columnName], typeof(T));
            }
        }
```

But i wonder, why can't I use:

`return (T)row[columnName];`

because it throws Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Int32'.!
But the same implicit conversion works:

`short x = 6;     int y = x; // <- this implicit conversion is ok`

And second question - is there any easiest way than using Convert class ? I heard, that using it is slow.

Comment: Why is it not handy to use `int?` instead of `default(T)`. That means you get 0 instead of null and you might not know if this is a valid value or just a not existing value. With `int?` you can easily fallback to `0` if desired: `int result = row.Field<int?>("Col") ?? 0;`

Comment: Because, in queries there is sometimes null and sometimes -1, and sometimes 0 - and i want to have always 0. I dont want to modify query (ex to use COALESCE).

Comment: So you want to treat -1,null,0 all like 0? Well, what's wrong with `int value = row.Field<int?>("col") ?? 0; if(value < 0) value = 0;`

Comment: Yes, -1, null, 0 =>0. There is nothing wrong in your code. I just looking for short/smart solution. Maybe it is force of habit, to Delphi q.FieldByName('COLUMNINT').AsInteger